# Swift iOS: Set Gradient Background To A UITextView?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextview

I'm trying to apply gradient background to a UITextView object, not sure if it's possible because I get white background instead.

Here is my UIView extension:

```
extension UIView{

func setTextGradient(startColor:UIColor,endColor:UIColor)
{
    let gradient:CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.colors = [startColor.cgColor, endColor.cgColor]
    gradient.locations = [0.0 , 1.0]
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
    gradient.frame = self.bounds
    self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
}
```

Here where I assign gradient to the text view:

```
        detailTxtView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    detailTxtView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    detailTxtView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
    detailTxtView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
    detailTxtView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true

    detailTxtView.setTextGradient(startColor: Constants.Colors.bluLight, endColor: Constants.Colors.silver)

    // Set up text
    let attributedTxt = NSMutableAttributedString(string: titleStr, attributes:[NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Jazeel-Bold", size: 24)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: Constants.Colors.bluLight])

    attributedTxt.append(NSAttributedString(string: "\n\n\(detailStr)", attributes:[NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HacenTunisia", size: 20)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: Constants.Colors.aluminum]))

    let txtStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    txtStyle.alignment = .center
    let length = attributedTxt.string.count
    attributedTxt.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value: txtStyle, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: length))

    detailTxtView.attributedText = attributedTxt
```

Here are the colors in the Constants class:

```
    struct Colors{ 
    static let bluDark      = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 51/255, green: 50/255, blue: 80/255, alpha: 1)
    static let bluLight     = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 68/255, green: 85/255, blue: 138/255, alpha: 1)
    static let greenLight   = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 200/255, green: 255/255, blue: 132/255, alpha: 1)
    static let mercury      = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 235/255, green: 235/255, blue: 235/255, alpha: 1)
    static let silver       = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 214/255, green: 214/255, blue: 214/255, alpha: 1)
    static let magnesium    = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 192/255, green: 192/255, blue: 192/255, alpha: 1)
    static let aluminum     = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 169/255, green: 169/255, blue: 169/255, alpha: 1)
    static let blu2         = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 88/255, green: 120/255, blue: 166/255, alpha: 0.2)
    static let bluLighter = #colorLiteral(red: 0.451, green: 0.5569, blue: 0.8314, alpha: 1) /* #738ed4 */
}
```

I always get white background when using the gradient method. Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: you need to set location
gradientLayer.locations = [0.5 , 0.5]

Comment: I hope your colours are making problem

Comment: Ur getting errors or something else

Comment: I always get white background, I added my colors to the question

Comment: pls check the constraint it's a constraint problem

Comment: it's anchored to right left and bottom with a height, I can't detect the error in constraint

Comment: Did you get answer please post i 'm eager to see that one ....

Comment: Hi Spynet thanks for the followup, it magically worked! I have no idea how. Just used the exact code in my question. I guess there was a bug somehow in xCode.

Comment: I guess I know now, I needed to set the gradient after setting the text attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gradient worked when I set it after setting text attributes

```
detailTxtView.attributedText = attributedTxt
detailTxtView.setTextGradient(startColor: Constants.Colors.silver, endColor: Constants.Colors.bluDark)
```

Answer (score 4):

i think you forget location

```
extension UIView
{
   func setGradient(startColor:UIColor,endColor:UIColor)
    {
        let gradient:CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.colors = [startColor.cgColor, endColor.cgColor]
        gradient.locations = [0.0 , 1.0]
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
        gradient.frame = self.bounds
        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
     }
}
```

use

```
txtView.setGradient(startColor: UIColor.blue, endColor: UIColor.green)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: still not working can you see my updated code? thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `locations` property of `CAGradientLayer`

```
extension UIView{

    func setGriadientBackrnd(color1: UIColor, color2: UIColor){
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds
        gradientLayer.colors = [color1.cgColor, color2.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.locations = [0.5 , 0.5] //here you can set percentage of color part are display betwin 0 to 1
        layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that and didn't make a difference, I updated the question

Answer (score 1):

[Please check your code Output](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5Cvv4A2xDy3YlVOdE1EWUFJMjg)

Hi Folk try like that hope you helps,

```
    let titleStr = "Hi How are you ?"
    let detailStr = "HI How UR preparation..."
    gradientTextview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    gradientTextview.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    gradientTextview.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
    gradientTextview.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
    gradientTextview.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true

    gradientTextview.setGradient(startColor: UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 68/255, green: 85/255, blue: 138/255, alpha: 1), endColor: UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 214/255, green: 214/255, blue: 214/255, alpha: 1))


    let attributedTxt = NSMutableAttributedString(string: titleStr, attributes:[NSFontAttributeName: UIFont (name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 20)! , NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 68/255, green: 85/255, blue: 138/255, alpha: 1)])

    attributedTxt.append(NSAttributedString(string: "\n\n\(detailStr)", attributes:[NSFontAttributeName: UIFont (name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 18)! , NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 169/255, green: 169/255, blue: 169/255, alpha: 1)]))

    let txtStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    txtStyle.alignment = .center
    let length = attributedTxt.string.characters.count
    attributedTxt.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value: txtStyle, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: length))

    gradientTextview.attributedText = attributedTxt
```

===============================================================

```
extension UIView{

func setTextGradient(startColor:UIColor,endColor:UIColor)
{
    let gradient:CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.colors = [startColor.cgColor, endColor.cgColor]
    gradient.locations = [0.0 , 1.0]
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
    gradient.frame = self.bounds
    self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
}
```

**NOTE:-**

instead of view you can add self.gradientTextview also...

Comment: @fullmoon Still Facing issue please report me

Comment: Appreciate it man, weirdly it still showing white background. The gradient works fine when I use it with UIView objects, only stops working when used with UITextView. This uitextview is inside a collection view cell class , and using iOS 11 simulator, not sure if this of importance

Comment: @fullMoon please check the constraints you're using for me also it shows empty screen only, pls check the console any misaligned things

Comment: I played with the constraint and repositioned the text view, and still getting white